# Eclipse Luna Doesn't Display JFrames

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing

I'm using a Mac and for some reason Eclipse Luna won't run any of my programs that use a `JFrame`. The problem persists on a fresh installation of Luna but using Juno or Kepler, the frame displays just fine. I'm also using Java 8. My classmates can run the same code fine on Kepler as well (Windows and Mac). It also runs fine if I run it through Terminal. I have no clue why Luna won't display `JFrame`s; does anyone know what the issue could possibly be?

EDIT: Any program that runs through the console runs just fine.

Comment: What does 'won't run' mean? Do you get an error message? If so what is it? Exactly how are you running the program? My Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 with Java 1.8 update 20 runs JFrame programs without problem.

Comment: I'm running it with by right-clicking the project and hitting "run". Literally nothing happens. If I change the main method to include something like `System.out.print("Hello");` then it prints "Hello" and does nothing else.

Comment: What 'run'? The right click menu should have 'Run As > Java Application' but it does not have a 'Run' option.

Comment: So what are the contents of the unchanged main method?